# changing 26 to 700 wheels on mountain bike?

Tags: wheels, bike-fit

I have a nice colnago mountain bike w/26 wheels and disc brakes; am thinking of changing to 700 wheels as i am 6'3" and bike feels  somewhat small. would this negatively affect ride, handling, geometry...? i tried on  27.5 wheels  from other bike, and they do fit.i am just an older recreational rider and am wondering if this would work . thanks guys

Comment: Note that most 26 inch wheels are 559mm, 25.7 wheels are 584, and 700 wheels are 622.  Just because a 25.7 fits nicely says nothing about a 700.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you can get the wheels in the frame with enough clearance and have the brakes work, you're OK.

Note that your proposed wheel swap may not give a significantly larger outer diameter of the wheel+tire (which if increased would make the bike a bit taller riding).

---

Now to what I think is the answer to your real question: 
If the bike is feeling small, the wheel size is one (minor) portion of it; the rest of the geometry (top tube length, seat tube length, stem length, etc.) have a far larger effect than the wheel size has. So, you may need to switch frames.